# Can a project contain other projects with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a software project that has the following structure.

```
- Library A
- Library B
- Main program
- Test for Main
```

I have four project files (csproj) for each one, but it would be good if I can debugging/compile those projects in a single solution explorer.

- Does Visual Studio (especially for 2010) support this feature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, projects cannot contain other projects in Visual Studio.  Solutions are used as the container for projects.

I don't understand why a project container would work but a solution would not.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: I see that I can have multiple csproj files, and the sln file can contain them. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can have what's called a solution file which contains all of your projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple projects to a solution by right clicking the top level solution and selecting Add -> Add Existing Project or Add -> New Project

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're thinking of is a solution.  A solution can contain one or more projects:

```
- My Solution
  - Library A
  - Library B
  - Main Program
  - Test For Main
```

I don't think this is available for VS2010 Express.

Comment: In VS2008 Express versions, solution files are supported, but the default for new projects is a project file rather than a soloution file.  I know you can load solutions created by the licensed versions, and I think I remeber reading that you can create solutions, even though a new program created with the express edition does not have a solution file by default.  Not sure if 2010 is the same or not.

Comment: I found this article http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/e0aede23-6558-42a1-9fe1-440fd45d3dd4 which seems to imply that there was a restriction is 2008, but cannot find anything either way for 2010

Answer (score 0):

You can have solution folders to organize multiple projects, but you can not have a project within projects.

another option is to just move all the class files to one project and create folders for each library that you have. I do this many times to reduce solution clutter

Comment: 'areas' are a feature of Asp.Net MVC 2, not VS 2k10